# Random background gradient function issues in identifying the elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have developed a program where my first function (GetValue()) pick two colors from the array of colors I created.
Those colors get stored in variables - randomColor1 and randomColor2

next, I created a function to make my background gradient.
For this I calling the elements (randomColor1 and randomColor2). But it is not working and showing error as undefined for  (randomColor1 and randomColor2) and my background color is not changing.

lastly, I have merge both the above function.

Please help me fix my code. I dont understand what is the mistake I did. I am a rookie.

Here are my codes

```
function GetValue() {
  var myarray = new Array( "#ff0000", "#ffe100", "#95ff00", "#2c8d94", "#ad6428", "#28ad9d");
  var randomColor1 = myarray.splice(
    Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray.length),1)[0];
  var randomColor2 = myarray.splice(
    Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray.length),1)[0];

  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = randomColor1 + randomColor2;
}


var styles = ["to right", "to bottom right", "-90deg"];


function applyChanges(randomColor1, randomColor2) {
  var randomColor1 = GetValue();
  var randomColor2 = GetValue();
  var bg = "";
  var style = Math.floor(Math.random() * styles.length);
  bg = "linear-gradient(" + styles[style] + "," + randomColor1 + "," + randomColor2 + ")";
  $("body").css("background", bg);
  $("#myInput").text(bg);
}

function changeBg() {
  var randomColor1 = GetValue();
  var randomColor2 = GetValue();
  applyChanges(randomColor1, randomColor2);
}
```

Thank you

Comment: `GetValue()` returns nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `GetValue()` returns nothing so one way of fixing it is by returning both colors and then assigning them as shown:

```
function GetValue() {
    var myarray = new Array("#ff0000", "#ffe100", "#95ff00", "#2c8d94", "#ad6428", "#28ad9d");
    var randomColor1 = myarray.splice(
        Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray.length), 1)[0];
    var randomColor2 = myarray.splice(
        Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray.length), 1)[0];

    /* Return like this*/
    return [randomColor1, randomColor2];
}
```

And the changeBG() is changed to

```
function changeBg() {
    /* Get colors like this since they are returned like this*/
    var [randomColor1, randomColor2] = GetValue();
    /* Log it to see what colors they are*/
    console.log(randomColor1, randomColor2);
    /* Call the apply method*/
    applyChanges(randomColor1, randomColor2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You had to simplyfy your GetValue-function: Just create 1 value and **return** it. The rest is ok.
Let's try it here:

```js
function GetValue() {
  var myarray = new Array( "#ff0000", "#ffe100", "#95ff00", "#2c8d94", "#ad6428", "#28ad9d");
  return myarray.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray.length),1)[0];
}


var styles = ["to right", "to bottom right", "-90deg"];


function applyChanges(randomColor1, randomColor2) {
  var randomColor1 = GetValue();
  var randomColor2 = GetValue();
  var bg = "";
  var style = Math.floor(Math.random() * styles.length);
  bg = "linear-gradient(" + styles[style] + "," + randomColor1 + "," + randomColor2 + ")";
  $("body").css("background", bg);
  $("#myInput").text(bg);
}

function changeBg() {
  var randomColor1 = GetValue();
  var randomColor2 = GetValue();
  applyChanges(randomColor1, randomColor2);
}

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    changeBg();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='message'></div>
<input id='myInput'>
<button id='btn'>Click me</button>
```